# Disposing a non-component when a form disposes?

Tags: c#, winforms, idisposable

I have a form that has a member that implements `IDisposable` but not `IComponent`.  I need to dispose it when the form disposes.  Unfortunately the form's dispose is already implemented in the automatically generated portion of the code, and is not partial.

How can I dispose this object?

Comment: A bit of an iffy call to put it in the Designer file but they did want to leave the main one clean.  Moving is not an issue, the designer is really only interested in the marked region.  You can change the item template to make it permanent, if you really want to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Override [Form.Dispose(bool)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aw58wzka.aspx) in your form, and dispose of your object there.

In order to understand how this works, you can refer to MSDN's page on [Implementing a Dispose Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs2xkftw.aspx).  The Form class follows this pattern, which allows you to override `Dispose(bool)` in subclasses.  (Just make sure to call `base.Dispose(disposing)` correctly in your override, as well.)

---

If you aren't comfortable moving this from the .designer.cs file into your main .cs file, the other option is to subscribe to your own [FormClosed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosed.aspx) event, and dispose of your resources in that event handler.  MSDN recommends this approach - from the docs for FormClosed:

> You can use this event to perform tasks such as freeing resources used by the form and to save information entered in the form or to update its parent form.

Comment: Form Designer has already overriden Form.Dispose() for him. Unfortunately it's a generated method (and, as such, you shouldn't add custom code to it).

Comment: @Justin: You need to move it, if you're using the designer, into your code - it does work, and doesn't get recreated.

Comment: @Justin: I just added another (potentially better) option, too ;)

Comment: @Reed - +1 for the second option. I definitely like it better than relying on Designer behavior.

Comment: @Justin: I probably do too, though I wish MS provided an extensibility point via an override for this directly... I like using the "normal" IDisposable pattern when possible.

Comment: @Reed - I definitely agree with you there.

Comment: I went with moving the dispose, which seems to work fine.  If it does cause a problem it's an easy enough fix.

Comment: Controls and forms implement a "Disposed" method; I would think that could be better than FormClosed.

Comment: @supercat: MSDN specifically recommends using FormClosed - though Disposed will work, it can happen at odd times, since Dispose() may not be called when expected.

Comment: @Reed Copsey: If a form is shown with ShowDialog, closing it will not automatically dispose it; not only can properties of the form still be queried--the form may also be re-shown.  If the nature of resources required by the form is such that they can be safely disposed of and reacquired if the form is closed and reopened, then it would probably be good to acquire the resources in Load, and release them in FormCLosed.  Otherwise, acquire them in New and release them in Disposed.  Does that sound like the right pattern?

Answer (score 2):

You can move the overridden `Dispose(bool)` method to your side of the partial class. From experience, it does not get recreated in the designer part.